# Unable to reach apache web server through nginx proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, web-server, proxy

I have apache server running on the following 23.xxx.xxx.10:80. I am trying to reach to one of the folders ( /var/www/cfbrokerlogs) using nginx proxy as defined below. However, when i try to reach from my browser I get net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS . I am not sure what do i need to turn on to make it work ?

nginx.conf

```
location /cfbrokerlogs/ {
  proxy_pass                 http://23.xxx.xxx.10:80/cfbrokerlogs;
  proxy_set_header           X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
  proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-Server  $host;
  proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
  proxy_set_header           Host  $host;

  client_max_body_size       10m;
  client_body_buffer_size    128k;

  proxy_connect_timeout      90;
  proxy_send_timeout         90;
  proxy_read_timeout         90;

  proxy_buffer_size          4k;
  proxy_buffers              4 32k;
  proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
  proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
}
```

Apache configuration  (apache2.conf)

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>


    WSGIDaemonProcess _graphite processes=5 threads=5 display-name='%{GROUP}' inactivity-timeout=120 user=_graphite group=_graphite
    WSGIProcessGroup _graphite
    WSGIImportScript /usr/share/graphite-web/graphite.wsgi process-group=_graphite application-group=%{GLOBAL}
    WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/share/graphite-web/graphite.wsgi

   Alias /content/ /usr/share/graphite-web/static/
      <Location "/cfbrokerlogs/">
      SetHandler None  
      Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
      Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, OPTIONS"
      Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, authorization, accept"
       </Location>

      Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
      Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, OPTIONS"
      Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, authorization, accept"


             Alias /cfbrokerlogs  /var/www/cfbrokerlogs
            <Directory /var/www/cfbrokerlogs>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
            </Directory>

    </VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [nginx's documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) :

> If the proxy_pass directive is specified with a URI, then when a request is passed to the server, the part of a normalized request URI matching the location is replaced by a URI specified in the directive.

So here this means if you hit `http://<domain>/cfbrokerlogs/foo` then it will be forwarded as `http://23.xxx.xxx.10:80/cfbrokerlogsfoo` by the `proxy_pass` directive.

Add a trailing slash to the `proxy_pass` directive URI or remove it from the location.

Comment: Thanks I did try to add the trailing slash but now I see net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in the console of my browser. any idea ?

Comment: @user3846091 Check that nginx is actually running.

Comment: I did a stop/start of nginx and it appears to be working now. Thanks a lot for pointing out the error for me.